# RenderAction ViewBag Empty on the View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am invoking a RenderAction from a View as shown below:

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("GetOptions", "Product", new {ProductId = Model.ProductId});

   var options = ViewBag.Options; 

}
```

Inside the GetOptions I populate the ViewBag as shown below:

```
public ActionResult GetOptions(..) {

     // do some other stuff 
     ViewBag.Options = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serializer(options); 

     return Content(somelongstring); 
}
```

But when I debug inside the var options is always null. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are the parameters for  `ActionResult GetOptions(..)`?

Comment: ProductId. The GetOptions is fired and I can see the ViewBag.Options populated in the controller but when it reaches the view it is null.

Comment: It's not available probably because you are returning string content rather than returning a `ViewResult`. If your main view has the `Model.ProductId` why can't it obtain the options and set the ViewBag.Options in its controller action?

Comment: I fixed the issue using TempData.